# Excel formula formation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A stated item name just like Orange,Mango,for example,and in column B stated the value of each item.

```
   A                                   B
1.Orange                              100
2.Mango                               200
3.Grape                               120
4.Mango                               110
5.Orange                              100
6.Mango                               110
```

It has thousands of rows ,I want the answer of total amount of each item.Means "Sum the the values of column B whenever the item name  in column A is same.

Comment: this is nothing related with android, so don't tag android...anyway your ans is here https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4970-excel-sum-by-group.html

Comment: please change android tag to excel tag

Comment: Use a pivot table in excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

Will return the sum of values in B for the criterium in cell A1. Just drag and drop or adapt to fit your needs